How to find solutions of this non-linear equation in a closed form with Mathematica?
I am solving in 14.1 on Windows that equation from "The Kvant",# 9, 2024, p. 55  by
Reduce[36*Cos[x + Cos[x]]*Cos[x - Cos[x]] + 9 == Pi^2, x, Reals]


Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

and
Reduce[36*TrigExpand[Cos[x + Cos[x]]*Cos[x - Cos[x]]] + 9 == Pi^2, x, Reals]//InputForm

The latter command returns the answer through Root[{-9 + Pi^2 - 18*Cos[Cos[#1]]^2 - 18*Cos[#1]^2 +  18*Sin[Cos[#1]]^2 + 18*Sin[#1]^2 & ,  5.26345856348413622617388170338704340685'20.3010321085961 04}] which is not a closed-form expression.
Next,
NSolve[36*Cos[x + Cos[x]]*Cos[x - Cos[x]] + 9 == Pi^2 && x >= Pi/3 && x <= 7*Pi/4, x, Reals]


{{x -> 2.12187}, {x -> 4.16132}, {x -> 5.26346}}

, but Mathematica incorrectly identifies it through
RootApproximant[x /. %[[1]]]


Root[6 - #1^2 - 3*#1^3 - 3*#1^4 + #1^5 + #1^6 - 5*#1^7 -  2*#1^8 + 2*#1^9 & , 3, 0]

as a root of  a polynomial of degree 9.

@the down-voter: What is incorrect in my question? It is unfair to down vote without any explaining comment.

I did not down vote your question; however, your statement that "Mathematica incorrectly identifies" the root is incorrect. The documentation for RootApproximant states "RootApproximant[x] converts the number x to one of the 'simplest' algebraic numbers that approximates it well." The approximation differs from the root by only 3.67386*10^-11

The result from RootApproximant is not incorrect. It's just not an actual root to the original equation.

@BobHanlon: You are right.  I have meant that the result of RootApprocimant is not reliable in many case. Let us consider NSolve[36*Cos[x + Cos[x]]*Cos[x - Cos[x]] + 9 == Pi^2 && x >= Pi/3 &&    x <= 7*Pi/4, x, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 20]. Then RootApproximant[2.12186590989434298771124363816462494173;20.] performs the root of a polynomial of degree 22.

Here is my answer.
a = Simplify[TrigExpand[Cos[x + Cos[x]]*Cos[x - Cos[x]]]] /. {Cos[x] -> t,  Cos[2 x] -> 2 t^2 - 1}


1/2 (-1 + 2 t^2 + Cos[2 t])

Reduce[9 + 36 a == Pi^2, t, Reals]


t == -(\[Pi]/6) || t == \[Pi]/6

Reduce[% /. t -> Cos[x], x, Reals]


(C[1] \[Element]  Integers && (x == -ArcCos[-(\[Pi]/6)] + 2 \[Pi] C[1] ||  x == ArcCos[-(\[Pi]/6)] + 2 \[Pi] C[1])) || (C[1] \[Element]  Integers && (x == -ArcCos[\[Pi]/6] + 2 \[Pi] C[1] ||  x == ArcCos[\[Pi]/6] + 2 \[Pi] C[1]))


Function is Pi-periodic
f = Function[x, 36*Cos[x + Cos[x]]*Cos[x - Cos[x]] + 9 - Pi^2];
f[x + Pi] == f[x]  (*True*)
f[ Pi/2 + x] == f[ Pi/2 - x] (*True*)

That's why it is sufficient to look for a solution in the range 0<x<Pi
NSolve[ f[x] == 0 && 0 <= x <= Pi  , x ]  (*{{x -> 1.01973}, {x -> 2.12187}}*)
 


This is not it. The question is about the symbolic solution  in a closed form. The Kvant is a journal for pupils.

@user64494 It would have been  helpful to mention the requirement "symbol" in the question itself

UlrichNeumann (@ does not work for you.): See the standard definition of a closed-form expression in Wiki.That link was cited several times in this forum.

Assume $x$ is a root of equation. It is straightforward to show $\pi -x$ is a solution.
q = TrigExpand[36*Cos[x + Cos[x]]*Cos[x - Cos[x]] + 9 == Pi^2] // 
  Simplify
r = q /. x -> Pi - x // Simplify
q === r 

=>

The translation of the question asks for sum of roots that are interval $(\pi/3,7\pi/4)$: $\pi$ is the solution.The relevant roots can be found:
{r1, r2} = x /. FindRoot[q, {x, #}] & /@ {1, 2}
r1 + r2
Plot[9 + 18 Cos[2 x] + 18 Cos[2 Cos[x]] - Pi^2, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]



This is not it. The question is about the symbolic solution  in a closed form. The Kvant is a journal for pupils.

You have mistaken even calculating the sum of the roots belonging to $(\pi/3,7\pi/4)$.
